# Is it ok to use map to apply function to arguments list and ignore the results?

Tags: python

Do you think that it is OK to use map for an applying function to arguments list and ignore the results?

```
map(foo, bar)
```

It may appears as bug to person who is reading code.

Comment: Isn't this the whole point of map?  From the docs:  "Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results."

Comment: Maybe, but I fill disturbance in the force when I'm calling map and throw away result.

Comment: The whole purpose of map is to be used for functional programing. Intentionally using a functional programing construct to create side effects should disturb the force.

Comment: Ahh, got it, that does but a spin on the use case.

Comment: The fact that you do _not_ plan to use the resulting list is crucial to the question, and should be mentioned in it.

Comment: Owen S. You are right. I have updated question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want the result using map is a perfectly fine way to apply a function to each item in a list, although many find it clearer to write it as a list comprehension or generator:

```
result = [foo(x) for x in bar]
```

However if you don't intend to use the result of the function call and are interested only in the side-effects then you should write using a procedural style instead:

```
for x in bar:
    foo(x)
```

Comment: Also, python is highly optimized for this use. List comprehensions are you friend.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is frowned upon. Use a for loop unless you intend to make use of the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I hack it together:

```
from itertools import imap, ifilterfalse

tuple(ifilterfalse(None, imap(lambda x: x+1, range(10))))
```

That `tuple` will always be empty (given this input).